# What are different ways to implement behaviour on click event in ASP.NET with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have "inherited" a project in ASP.NET with C# and I know for sure a certain stored procedure is associated with pressing a button called button_Search (I have confirmed this also with SQL Server profiler).
However, the method associated with clicking the button is empty:

```
protected void button_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Where else could that behaviour (running that stored procedure that returns a select which is then tied to a gridview) be implemented in ASP.NET, if not in the button_Search_Click?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Clicking the button causes a postback so it cloud be in any of the page lifecycle methods (page_load etc.)

Comment: check the onClick attribute of button.It need not be binded to button_Search_Click

Comment: There are many possible ways of answering this question. I suggest you to search the name of that stored procedure in your aspx and cs files, and from there you can deduce how it is being related to that button. If not, add that part of code to this question so we may help you out more accurately.

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
     if (IsPostBack){ //confirms it's a PostBack and not initial load
        Button myButton = (Button)(sender as Page).FindControl("button_Search"); //find your button
        if (myButton.ID == "button_Search"){
            // your normal code (the code you intend in button_Search_Click )goes here...
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be any number of method/functions depending on the project structure.

Does the aspx page contain something like the code below?

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"  OnClientClick="JavacriptClick()" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

The OnClick function would specify a method in the codebehind file OnClientClick would be a javascript function which would imply an ajax call.

If none of the above are present the search button could be being used to trigger a postback and the logic is somewhere in the page life cycle.  It is not unusual to find some logic in the PageLoad method with in an if IsPostback statment.

With regards to the stored procedure being activated/populating the gridview check if the gridview has an SqlDataSource/ObjectDataSourcemore information can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479341.aspx for further details.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
  //Please check for below line code
  this.button_Search.clicked += CallStoredProc;
 }

protected void CallStoredProc(object sender, EventArgs e){
// Here the SP could be called
}
```

**Please check out for such code**